# Why #define UNICODE has no effect in windows

Tags: c++, windows

I have the following code:

```
#define UNICODE
// so strange??
GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                    sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
```

But the compiler still report error like this:

`error C2664: “DWORD K32GetModuleBaseNameA(HANDLE,HMODULE,LPSTR,DWORD)”: 无法将参数 3 从“wchar_t [260]”转换为“LPSTR” [E:\source\mh-gui\build\src\mhgui.vcxproj]`

Which means `cant convert param 3 from wchar_t[260] to LPSTR`. It's look's like that still looking for A version api?

Comment: I'd suggest that you should use the W functions directly. Not using the unicode aware functions always is kinda a sin in 2020.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must put

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
```

*BEFORE*

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

The Windows header uses `#ifdef UNICODE` (et al), so if you want to make the distinction count, the `#defines` must occur before the `#include`.

---

edit: Because these `#define`s are functionally global, the most reliable place to add them is in your compiler options, so the ordering doesn't matter then.

Comment: Better still add these defines to your compiler options, so they are set throughout the compilation.

Comment: And if using PCH, it really ought to be compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using visual studio, instead of defining UNICODE yourself you should enable the W version by right clicking the project in the solution explorer -> properties -> Advanced -> Change the "Character Set" option to "Use Unicode Character Set"